# SSRS shared data sources and shared schedule

Tags: ssrs, reporting

I am cleaning up our existing SSRS (report server) and would like a few suggestions and best practices in terms how it should be used. Currently each report has a connection and schedule. Would it be a good practice if I created a few shared schedules? What would be the impacts in terms of performance and resources? Also, would there be any impacts if I were to create a Data Source is SSRS and use that particular shared data source in reports? Also, if lets say 10 reports are scheduled to run at 1:00PM , would they queue or would they execute all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS has a number of configuration files, including RSReportServer.config.

Both Shared Schedules and Shared Data Sources are good things to create since they help you manage your configuration without giving each and every report it own schedule. View this as saving you some work.  Of course, independent Schedules and Data Sources will likely be needed for some reports.

Since you are concerned with overall load, note that the MaxQueueThreads configuration will control how many parallel reports can run at once.  0 means run as many as possible, but some other number (e.g. 3) will limit Reporting Services to run that number reports at one time.

If you have 10 reports on the same schedule the other reports will run as Queue Threads open up for use.

To configure appropriately need to know your resources available and configure appropriately.  Probably there will be a little trial and error until you get things balanced.